# How can I "pause" app for user to press a button? GTK

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am making an card game in C using GTK 3.0. I have two functions for two windows, openMenu() to open the menu and newGame() to create a new window with a card table. The player is playing against two bots which will choose their cards randomly. I need the player to start the game with choosing one card. 
Open Menu:

```
static void openMenu(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GObject *button;
    GError *error = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("menu_window_glade.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu_window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();
}
```

New Game:

```
void newGame(){
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkImage *image;
    widgetsPtrs *widgets = malloc(sizeof(widgetsPtrs));
    char imageStr[] = "image00";
    char aImgstr[] = "A0";
    char dImgstr[] = "D0";
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("game_glade.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "game_glade_window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    shuffleTheDeck();
    printAll(Deck);

    card *player = malloc(sizeof(card));
    card *leftBot = malloc(sizeof(card));
    card *rightBot = malloc(sizeof(card));

    deal(player, 0);
    deal(leftBot, 0);
    deal(rightBot, 0);

    /***************Puts images into buttons***********/
    tmpCard = player;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        tmpCard = tmpCard->next;
        imgPath[20] = zero + tmpCard->rank; 
        imgPath[21] = zero + tmpCard->suit;
        gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(widgets->w_playersHandPtr[i]), imgPath);   
    }

    int a = firstTurnCheck();
    playersTurn(player, leftBot, rightBot);
}
```

The problem comes from here: I've come with an idea of a loop, which can be broken only if the global bool is changed, which is changed in a function serving on click events. **However, the window with a game table doesn't show**, therefore I am never able to click a button, so the app freezes.

```
void playersTurn(card *player, card *leftBot, card *rightBot){
    bool DEFENDERTOOKTHECARDS = false;
    bool RBHASMORE = true;
    PLAYERCHOOSING = true;
    int attackCounter = 0;
    int *appearedRanks = calloc(9, sizeof(int));
    card *cardsOnTheTable = malloc(sizeof(card)); //cardsOnTheTable[0] is a pointer to the table
    char answer;

    puts("Player's Turn");
    puts("Choose a card.");
    /*****************The spot where the mistake might be****************/
    while(PLAYERCHOOSING);//PLAYERCHOOSING is a global bool.
    puts("You've chosen a card.");
}
```

On_card_click function:

```
void on_card_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *data){ 
    gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(data));
    PLAYERCHOOSING = false;
}
```

Comment: If you are comfortable with threads, use a while loop in a separate thread with a Sleep() function, and use a callback function for the button handler.

Comment: You **must not** block main loop. It does a lot of things: redraws widgets, handles scaling, system events like key presses or mouse clicks. Also you **must not** call GTK functions from other threads. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49235519/4226702) answer, it may clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @ryyker for the advice he's given.
The solution is based on threading. As I said, I've never worked with them before, but it took me like 15 mins to figure out everything I needed, so there is nothing to be afraid of :) There is my solution:

> 1. '#include < pthread.h >',
> 2. declare pthread_t thread in newGame(),
> 3. add pthread_create(&thread, NULL, playersTurn, NULL); into newGame()
> 4. you can leave 'while(PLAYERCHOOSING)' loop as it is.
> 5. compile with -lpthread flag.

Voila, you are amazing.

Comment: Since you are already using glib, i'd recommend migrating to `GThread`.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, this line is a problem: (as you guessed in your comment.)

```
while(PLAYERCHOOSING);//PLAYERCHOOSING is a global bool.
```

It will enter and never leave.
At the very least it should have the ability to check a flag to see if a button has been pressed:

```
while(PLAYERCHOOSING)
{
    if(buttonToggled)//define as another global boolean value, and set when button is pressed
    {
        PLAYERCHOOSING = false;
        buttonToggled = false;
    }
    else Sleep(1000); //sleep for 1 second
}
```

A better approach is to run the user interface in the primary thread, then put the housekeeping (button press detection and handling ) in a second thread.  A callback function could be defined as a button press handler.
(`void on_card_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *data)` appears to be a callback.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and advice. Unfortunately, that didn't work, I've put your modified loop into newGame, and put buttonToggled = true; into on_card_clicked.

Comment: My guess would be that GTK needs the newGame() to finish in order to show the window.

Comment: @Keetch -  I believe it would work best to read up on threads (`fork()`) in which to run the parts of code to catch the button push.  The UI will not be able to run, and be responsive in the same thread as an infinite loop such as this one.

Comment: I guess you are right. Thanks a lot for your help and directions! If you are interested I will tag you in my solution as soon as I find it.

Comment: @Keetch - Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174630/645128) to see if any would apply to you.  In my environment, I can create an entire user interface with buttons, sliders, etc, each with its own handler functions (callbacks) that are handled by the environment.  I would guess `gtk` should have documentation to help with this too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why so many people like using threads for anything. GTK has a main loop, use it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330436/gtk-and-serial-input-uart/48339606#48339606) for more on this). You can't use `sleep`, infinite loops, or any other blocking calls, otherwise you block the main loop that processes the UI events.

So wouldn't just putting:

```
PLAYERCHOOSING = true;
```

in `playersTurn`, and

```
PLAYERCHOOSING = false;
```

in `on_card_clicked` be enough?

Comment: Because they know nothing about Timers.